# How to use forever while running the express js server

Tags: node.js, express, forever

I want to use forever while running the express js server.Usually I used to start my server with npm start,but with forever how I can start express js server.If I am using node forever app.js command,server is not getting started.I am new to node and express.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

After giving forever start ./bin/www command.I am getting

```
C:\Users\Gourab>forever start ./bin/www
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up f
or at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: ./bin/www
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script C:\Users\Gourab\bin\www does not exist.
```

Comment: in your package.json file, what is the command in the 'start' script?

Comment: the command is  "node ./bin/www" @war1oc

Comment: In which file and how to set spinSleepTime and minUptime ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forever start ./bin/www
```

That is the command you need to run for you server to spin up.
Your package.json file should contain:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

You can use the following command to set the minUptime and spinSleepTime:

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 ./bin/www
```

Comment: I have added the error I am getting after giving this command@war1oc

Comment: you have to run the command from you project root, where the package.json file is

Comment: `-w` means it will watch for file changes, glad your problem was solved. can you please accept the answer if it worked :)